# Do I need special permision to make an app that allows users to access pre-existing websites and services

Tags: windows, permissions, uwp

There is not app for Tinder in the Windows App store. I got the idea of making one but when I looked on GitHub it looks like someone already made [one](https://github.com/brianhama/tinder) but he has not released it. But there are a lot of gaps in the Windows app store. Amazon, Bank of America ect. If I wanted to make my own apps to serve these gaps would I need special permission? If so, where would I get it?

Comment: Most common condition is You can make but not in the name of straight tinder, you use tinder app, tinder browser like name and you can read developer api usage and terms and condition of respective api provider. And tinder third party apps already available on store

Comment: And sir one compliment for you , you can start with microsoft virtual academy for free beginner, intermediate, and advance learning source. And you should ask question related to programming in SO if needed